# I would like to verify the divergence theorem in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, calculus

I would like to verify the divergence theorem if F(x, y, z) =<x^2y^2, y^2z^2 , z^2x^2> when the solid E is bounded by x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2 on top and z = (x^2+y^2)^1/2 on the bottom in MATLAB.

I know the function for the divergence but I need help with setting up the bounds.
`syms x y z F(x,y,z)=[x^2y^2, y^2z^2, z^2x^2]; div=divergence(F,[x,y,z])`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: since 13 minutes ago you posted same question in the Mathworks forum by know you probably have seen this https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/70371-divergence-theorem-gauss-ostrogradsky-s-to-measure-flow?s_tid=srchtitle_divergence%2520theorem_2

Answer (score 0):

try this

Divergence Theorem (Gauss’, Ostrogradsky’s) to Measure Flow
version 1.0.0 (2.62 KB) by Roche de Guzman

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/70371-divergence-theorem-gauss-ostrogradsky-s-to-measure-flow?s_tid=srchtitle_divergence%2520theorem_2